# How to return a Mono with a long running task inside map?

Tags: project-reactor

I want to transform data inside the map function of the Mono:

```
long result = 0.0;

return Mono.just(result).map(value -> {
    // do some long running transformation here
    // and assign it to result (maybe 5 seconds task)
    // in our case a request:

    Mono<Result> resultObject = service.getResult();

    resultObject.subscribe(new Subscriber<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
            System.out.println("subscribe: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

            s.request(1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Result result) {
            System.out.println("on next: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

            value = result.getValue(); // this is not 0.0
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("error " + t);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
             System.out.println("complete");
        }
    });

    return value;
});
```

If I call this I always get `0.0` as the result so it is returning before the map function is done. For me that does not make much sense. How else am I supposed to transform my result before returning it?

**EDIT**

I could do the following but in my opinion this is not an optimal solution:

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
long result = 0.0;

return Mono.just(result).map(value -> {
    // do some long running transformation here
    // and assign it to result (maybe 5 seconds task)
    // in our case a request:

    Mono<Result> resultObject = service.getResult();

    resultObject.subscribe(new Subscriber<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
            System.out.println("subscribe: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

            s.request(1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Result result) {
            System.out.println("on next: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

            value = result.getValue(); // this is not 0.0

            latch.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("error " + t);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
             System.out.println("complete");
        }
    });

    try {
        latch.await();

        return value;
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return -1.0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds exactly like what `flatMap` is for: if your long running task is asynchronous and can be represented as a `Publisher<T>` then it can be triggered asynchronously by `flatMap`.

Note that `Mono#flatMap(Function)` was called `Mono#then(Function)` in `3.0.x`.

So in 3.0.7:

```
Mono.just(param).then(p -> service.getResult(p));
```

And in 3.1.0.M3:

```
Mono.just(param).flatMap(p -> service.getResult(p));
```

Note that if you don't use the value (service doesn't have a parameter) then you probably can simply provide the continuation `Mono`, using `then(Mono)` (which is valid in both 3.0.x and 3.1.x):

```
Mono.just(paramThatGetsIgnored).then(service.getResult());
```

(but in that case the starting point of `Mono.just(...)` isn't terribly relevant)

Comment: note that the best strategy to migrate from 3.0.x `then` to 3.1.0 `flatMap` is to replace 3.0 usage of `Mono.flatMap` with `Mono.flatMapMany` THEN usage of `Mono.then(Function)` with `Mono.flatMap(Function)`. All other `then` variants without a single `Function` remain the same.